# Python 2.7 centos installation with MYSQLDB

Tags: python-2.7, mysql-python

Here are the steps i followd . I donot want to disturb Pythn2.6  which is already on server but i want to install python 2.7 separatly

```
 1) sudo yum install python27 python27-pip
```

`2) sudo yum -y install python27-devel libxslt-devel libffi-devel openssl-devel` `3) sudo yum install python27-MySQL-python`
I am getting the following error in installing MYSQLDB

```
Collecting MySQL-python
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    sh: mysql_config: command not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-ixxaPu/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 43, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "setup_posix.py", line 25, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ixxaPu/MySQL-python/
```

Please help me resolve it  or how to debug the issue

---

Answer (score 2):

The following should also work:

```
sudo yum whatprovides mysql_config
```

This will list packages that contain filenames that match against the string `mysql_config`.

Then simply install one of the packages suggested.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me trying to set up Python on Centos7/Plesk.  Had to install mariadb-devel,

Answer (score 1):

After struggling a day i found the answer many of the Blogs say to install

```
mysql-devel
```

But this is installing older version of mysql-5.1
Now We use percona so i tried searching the percona client current  version

```
yum list installed | grep -i percona
```

and installed the same Devel version Here are the commands

```
sudo yum install Percona-Server-devel-56.x86_64
```

This installed the mysql_config you can cross check with

```
which mysql_config
```

and then install

```
 sudo pip2.7 install MySQL-python
```

thats all its working